# java.lang.IllegalStateException in fragment

Tags: java, android

```
 private void changeFragment(Fragment targetFragment) {
        resideMenu.clearIgnoredViewList();
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, targetFragment, "fragment")
                .setTransitionStyle(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE)
                .commit();
    }
```

> android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction
>   FragmentManager.java:1864 2
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal
>   BackStackRecord.java:650 3
>   android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit BackStackRecord.java:609
>   4 com.example.ramzan.lazurd.MainActivity.changeFragment
>   MainActivity.java:391 5
>   com.example.ramzan.lazurd.MainActivity.onCreate MainActivity.java:156
>   6 android.app.Activity.performCreate Activity.java:6904 7
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   Instrumentation.java:1136 8
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   ActivityThread.java:3266 9
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   ActivityThread.java:3415 10 android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100
>   ActivityThread.java:229 11 android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage
>   ActivityThread.java:1821 12 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage
>   Handler.java:102 13 android.os.Looper.loop Looper.java:148 14
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main ActivityThread.java:7406 15
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke Method.java 16
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   ZygoteInit.java:1230 17 com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   ZygoteInit.java:1120

Comment: You should provide both a description and the code related to this exception. With only this, it's practically impossible to help

Comment: updated pls check now its error occur on just Samsung Galaxy Note8  ..

Answer (score 0):

I think you are need to find fragment transaction commit

like this `fragmentTransaction.commit();`

and change:

```
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```